# Is it possible to assign a function to function pointer dynamically?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to somehow declare and assign a function to function pointer `func` in `main()` without having an actual function `add()`?

Current Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    typedef int (*funcPtr)(int a, int b);
    funcPtr func = &add;
    std::cout << func(2,3) << std::endl;
}
```

Preferred Style: (if possible)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef int (*funcPtr)(int a, int b);
    funcPtr func = (funcPtr){return a + b}; // is something like this possible?
    std::cout << func(2,3) << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a way to assign a function to function pointer dynamically like my last code?

Comment: What would you be assigning?

Comment: @stark so I can pass it to another function

Comment: I didn't ask "why".

Comment: @stark Oh, I don't know what what you mean then. I'm trying to assign a function to a function pointer like I wrote.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is closer to `const auto func = [](const auto a, const auto b){ return a + b; };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda); which could convert to function pointer implicitly if capture nothing.

```
funcPtr func = [](int a, int b) {return a + b;};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/D7WFI9we3M7yZihT)